# load picture from android phone into byte[]

Tags: java, android, bitmap, buffer, arrays

I want to load a picture i have in the smartphone so i can than send it over the internet to a webservice i created.

Here i provide a sample code of what i am trying and not working.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
System.out.println("BITMAP: "+bm != null);
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bm.getWidth() *bm.getHeight());
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, buffer);
```

I made sure that bm isn't null with the system out print. I get a NullPointerException in ByteArrayOutputStream. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. Use file name with the path**

```
String[] files = null;
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"folder path");
if(path.exists())
{
    filename = path.list();
}
for(int i=0; i<count;i++)
{
     Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path.getPath()+"/"+ files[i]);
}
```